# voclabs is not authorized to perform: iam:AttachUserPolicy on resource: user Olivia because no identity-based policy allows the iam:AttachUserPolicy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

While performing the Module 8 challenge lab for AWS Academy Solutions Architecting course. I received the following error message while performing Task 4 when I go for adding `IAMReadOnlyAccess` to Olivia(an imaginary person who acts as Database Admin in this lab) :
`User: <arn> assumed-role/voclabs/<username> is not authorized to perform: iam:AttachUserPolicy on resource: user Olivia because no identity-based policy allows the iam:AttachUserPolicy action`. Here `<arn> and <username>` are most probably different for everyone hence I didn't explicitly mention them.

I would like to know how can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the mistake. Students don't have enough access to directly add policies to singular `Users` in this lab (as I was trying to do). We have to add policy to `User groups`. It worked when I attached the policies directly to `DBAdministrators` group (of which Olivia is a member).